# Dynamically adding divs and images during runtime - vb

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-3.5

I have a table full of users which includes a username and an image. What I'm trying to do is for every user in the table, I want to create a new div with a class of "user" which contains a label for their username and their image. Here's what I have so far:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim label1 As New Label
    label1.ID = "label1"
    label1.Text = "Username goes here"
    Controls.Add(label1)
End Sub
```

I found out how to add a label but I'm not sure how I'd position it, or add HTML elements with a label and image object inside them. Here's what I'm hoping the result will look like:

```
<div class="user">
        <h2> Username </h2>
        <img src="user.png">
</div>
```

Hopefully this could then be repeated as many times as necessary for each user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can do it like this, here an example in c#

```
        var div = new Panel();
        div.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<h1>hallo</h1>"));
        div.Controls.Add(new Image());
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(div);
```

Comment: Cheers, this is working great so far. Do you know how to make it so the new panel appears inside a content placeholder instead of at the bottom of the page?

Comment: A content placeholder or placeholder? Just place a placeholder on your page,i.e. phXYZ and use phXYZ.controls.add(div);

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use the asp:repeater control, you bind it the same way you bind a grid I.e

```
myRepeater.DataSource = results
myRepeater.DataBind
```

I will come back to to this an provide a full detailed explanation for this answer as I'm own my phone at the moment.

Comment: "I will come back to to this an provide a full detailed explanation for this answer as I'm own my phone at the moment." - Still waiting ;-)